# Message were not found on queue

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

Currently im doing a JMS application that needs to send message to queue and received a reply. I sent 3 messages to the queue and mdb will read the message. But the problem now is that mdb did not read all the 3 messages that were sent. It sometimes will display only 2 or 1 message. Can anyone help me through this? What and where should i check for error in order to make this work?

Comment: Can you post example code please? What have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got the solution. It is because i did the send and receive function together in the main method. I separated it into different method and it works. Such a silly mistake. Anyway, thanks :)